# Adding pubspec extension to project in root visual studio flutter

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart

I am trying to write a code in dart and I want to add dependencies so I added 'Pubspec Assist'
extension. when I tried to use it it showed me this message:
"

> Pubspec Assist: Pubspec file not found in workspace root. Open the pubspec file you would like to edit and try again. "

how do I place it in my workspace root. I'm new to dart and Vstudio and I need detailed explanation please. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing is to do as it says. Either open a project where the `pubspec.yaml` file is at the root, or **open the file in the editor and then start Pubspec Assist**.
and Sometimes you need to restart your ide or code editor for some extensions to work **so try restarting your ide/code editor**

Hope this was helpful enough
Below is the correct order of how your flutter project can be arranged, your `pubspec.yaml` file must be inside your project's directory as `myproject/pubspec.yaml`
and not inside any other subdirectories its the best practice which you should follow for flutter project.
and if this didnt worked out for you just try running `flutter clean` and then `flutter create .`

[image]